# angular-js can't save changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have admin interface - can add\delete\edit users. This is part of html, nothing important, but for sure (ng-controller and ng-app include in my index file).

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <form name="myForm2">
                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                    <span ng-show="!editMode">{{user.username}}</span>
                    <input ng-show="editMode" type="text" name="username" ng-model="current.username" required >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                    <span ng-show="!editMode">{{user.firstname}}</span>
                    <input ng-show="editMode" type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="current.firstname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                    <span ng-show="!editMode">{{user.lastname}}</span>
                    <input ng-show="editMode" type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="current.lastname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 cell">
                    <span ng-show="!editMode">{{user.age}}</span>
                    <input ng-show="editMode" type="number" name="age" ng-model="current.age" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 cell">
                    <span ng-show="!editMode">{{user.email}}</span>
                    <input ng-show="editMode" type="email" name="email" ng-model="current.email" required>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-md-3 cell">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-show="!button1" ng-click="edit(user); userEddit = !userEddit; button1 = !button1; editMode = !editMode">Eddit</button>
                <span ng-show="userEddit">
                    <h6>Save changes?<br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs col-md-offset-1" ng-click="save(user); userEddit = !userEddit; button1 = !button1; editMode = !editMode" ng-disabled="myForm2.$invalid">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs col-md-offset-1" ng-click="cancel(user); userEddit = !userEddit; button1 = !button1; editMode = !editMode">Cancel</button>
                    </h6>   
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 cell">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="!button" ng-click="userDelete = !userDelete; button = !button">Del</button>
                <span ng-show="userDelete">
                    <h6>Sure?
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs col-md-offset-1" ng-click="removeRow(user.username)">Del</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs col-md-offset-1" ng-click="userDelete = !userDelete; button = !button">Cancel</button>
                    </h6>   
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

There is controllers.js

```
'use strict';
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
    {"username":"user1","firstname":"John","lastname":"Anderson","age":25,"email":"john.anderson@testtask.com"},
    {"username":"user2","firstname":"Paul","lastname":"Winfred","age":27,"email":"winfredMPaul@dayrep.com"},
    {"username":"user3","firstname":"Adan","lastname":"Kelley","age":64,"email":"adanMKelley@jourrapide.com"},
    {"username":"user4","firstname":"Vernon","lastname":"McCall","age":70,"email":"vernonKMcCall@teleworm.us"},
    {"username":"user5","firstname":"Ernest","lastname":"Heflin","age":38,"email":"ernestMHeflin@jourrapide.com"},
    {"username":"user6","firstname":"John","lastname":"Barton","age":52,"email":"JohnPBarton@jourrapide.com"},
    {"username":"user7","firstname":"Jessica","lastname":"Lara","age":25,"email":"JessicaRLara@jourrapide.com"}
    ];

$scope.removeRow = function(username){              
    var index = -1;     
    var comArr = eval( $scope.users );
    for( var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++ ) {
        if( comArr[i].username === username ) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( index === -1 ) {
        alert( "Something gone wrong" );
    }
    $scope.users.splice( index, 1 );        
};  

$scope.current = {};
$scope.copy = {};

$scope.edit = function(user){
    $scope.copy = angular.copy(user);
    $scope.current = angular.copy(user);    
};

$scope.save = function(user){
    user = $scope.current;
    $scope.current = {};
    $scope.copy = {};
};

$scope.cancel = function(user) {
    user = $scope.copy;
    $scope.current = {};
    $scope.copy = {};
};
});
```

My problem - that i can't save changes. 
But if i do that

```
$scope.edit = function(user){
        $scope.copy = angular.copy(user);
        $scope.current = angular.copy(user);    
    };

    $scope.save = function(user){
        $scope.users[0] = $scope.current;
        $scope.current = {};
        $scope.copy = {};
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(user) {
        $scope.users[0] = $scope.copy;
        $scope.current = {};
        $scope.copy = {};
    };
```

It will work only for first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
user = $scope.current;
```

this is the problem. I think all your methods have problems, for save for example you can use this :

```
$scope.users.push(user);
```

this will add your user to users array.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not perfect. I meant i can't save changes

Answer (score 0):

Found answer: just make id to my database

```
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
    $scope.users[i].id = i;
    }
```

Then just checked matches in cycle

```
$scope.edit = function(user){
    $scope.copy = angular.copy(user);
    $scope.current = angular.copy(user);    
};

$scope.save = function(user){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.users[i].id === $scope.current.id){
            $scope.users[i]=$scope.current;
        }
    }
    $scope.current = {};
    $scope.copy = {};
};

$scope.cancel = function(user) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.users[i].id === $scope.copy.id){
            $scope.users[i]=$scope.copy;
        }
    }
    $scope.current = {};
    $scope.copy = {};
};
```

Thanks anyway